# Recorrer array php con número indefinido de anidaciones

Tags: php

Tengo una función que suma los valores de un array y saca la suma del total. Cuando un array contiene otro anidado, no hay problema, lo suma todo perfectamente:

```
$array = [3, 5, 9] //Este ejemplo lo recorre perfectamente.
$array = [3, 4, [5,9], 3] //este también.

public function sumaArray ($array) {

$res = 0;

  foreach($array as $i)
    {
      $res += $i ." ";
    foreach($i as $anidado)
        {
        $res += $anidado ." ";
        }
    }

echo $res;

}
```

El problema es cuando me encuentro con más de una anidación:

```
$array3 = [3, 4, [5,9,[7,3,1,], 3] //este no porque no entra en el array anidado dentro del array.
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que recorra todos los valores independientemente del numero de anidaciones que existan?

Answer (score 1):

estuve mirando tu código y lo que se me ocurrio fue llamar a la misma función de manera recursiva hasta recorrer todo el array.

```
<?php

$array1 = [3, 5, 9]; //Este ejemplo lo recorre perfectamente.
$array2 = [3, 4, [5, 9], 3]; //este también.
$array3 = [3, 4, [5, 9, [7, 3, 1]], 3]; //este no porque no entra en el array anidado dentro del array.

function sumaArray($array)
{
    $res = 0;
    foreach ($array as $numero) {

        if (is_array($numero)) {

            $res += sumaArray($numero);
        } else {
            $res += $numero;
        }
    }
    return $res;
}

echo sumaArray($array2);
```

Resultado:

```
24
```

Ahora si recorre completamente el array y te devuelve la suma.

Explicacion resumida:

Lo que hace es comprobar si es un array, si es un array recorre esa parte del array y te devuelve la suma y la vas acumulando, y cuando no queda nada mas que recorrer te devuelve la suma completa.

Ejemplo donde que concatena cada resultado de cada sección del array y muestra cada suma:

```
<?php

$array1 = [3, 5, 9]; //Este ejemplo lo recorre perfectamente.
$array2 = [3, 4, [5, 9], 3]; //este también.
$array3 = [3, 4, [5, 9, [7, 3, 1]], 3]; //este no porque no entra en el array anidado dentro del array.

function sumaArray($array)
{

    $concatenado = '';
    $res = 0;

    foreach ($array as $numero) {

        if (is_array($numero)) {

            $concatenado = $concatenado . ' ' . sumaArray($numero);
        } else {

            $res += $numero;
        }
    }

    $concatenado = $res . ' ' . $concatenado;
    return (string) $concatenado;
}

echo sumaArray($array2);
```

Resultado:

```
10 14
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Funciona!!

Answer (score 1):

Se puede hacer utilizando la función de suma siempre que un elemento sea un `array`, para ello as recorrer los elementos del `array` preguntamos si ese elemento es a su vez un `array` y en ese caso aplicamos la misma función.

```
$a1 = array(3,5,9); 
$a2 = array(3,4,array(5,9),3); 
$a3 = array(3,4,array(5,array(9,5)),3);
$a4 = array(3,4,array(5,array(9,array(5,5))),3);

function sumaArray($array) {
  $res = 0; $res_aux = 0;
  foreach($array as $i) {
      if (is_array($i)) {
          $res_aux = sumaArray($i);
          $res += $res_aux;
          $res_aux = 0;
      } else {
        $res += $i;
      }
  }
  return $res;
}

echo sumaArray($a1)."<br>";
echo sumaArray($a2)."<br>";
echo sumaArray($a3)."<br>";
echo sumaArray($a4)."<br>";
```

Resultado:

```
17
24
29
34
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Funciona!!

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma alternativa de hacerlo es con [array_walk_recursive()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) el cual recorrerá recursivamente todos los elementos de un `array` multidimensional aplicandole una `función llamable`, [callable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

En este caso, para reducir aún más código, el `callable` se reemplazó por una [función anónima](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.anonymous.php), algo como un "lambda" en otros lenguajes de programación.

```
<?php
function SumarArray($array) {
    $res = 0;
    array_walk_recursive($array, function($value) use (&$res) { $res += $value; });
    return $res;
}
```

Nota: Debido a que `$res` está fuera del ámbito de la función anónima, es necesario pasarle la referencia, `&$res`, para que acumule la suma del valor de cada elemento fuera de la función.

Probando la salida

```
echo SumarArray(array(3, 5, 9)); // 17
echo SumarArray(array(3, 4, array(5,9), 3)); // 24
echo SumarArray(array(3, 4, array(5, 9, array(7,3,1)), 3)); // 35
```